# Ubuntu doesn't boot after reinstalling Python 3

Tags: python3

I uninstalled Python 3 using

```
sudo apt purge python3
```

and reinstalled using

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

and finally rebooted computer using`sudo reboot`. But after this, computer doesn't start.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is because you *purged* the installation. Ubuntu relies on Python 3 and all of it's relative files to boot - a lot of the OS uses .py files. Removing all files means the OS has no way to boot now. `sudo apt install python3` only reinstalls Python, not the packages or other files that were there before.

Two options:

-Reinstall all packages and files via a Live USB. Boot into a Live USB, and copy the entire `/` directory where all Python files are. This doesn't always work.

-Backup all important files and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. But I have dual boot with Windows 10.
Boot Manager is Grub How to reinstall Ubuntu without crashing Boot Manager or Partitions?

Comment: @MI12 i just told you how. You can install Ubuntu to a Live USB and then copy over the necessary files from the USB's `/` directory into your Ubuntu partition's `/` directory. This doesn't always work though.